# Finding non-trivial eigenvectors for matrices with transcendental eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to follow along in a book by following an example that the author uses.  However, I am completely stuck on one thing.  I can't understand how the author got $A$ and $C$ to equal what they do (Eqs 4.6.18) from the system of equations (Eqs 4.6.9).  I know how to find eigenvectors for regular systems of equations, but I haven't experienced this kind before.  I've tried looking at it different ways and have put it into Mathematica, however, everything shows $A$ and $C$ to both be $\mathbf{0}$.  Any help in figuring it out would be appreciated.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/13fL1.jpg

$A \mu sin(\mu h)+C[\mu h cos(\mu h)+\frac{2}{1+v} sin(\mu h)]=0$
$A \mu cos(\mu h)+C[-\mu h sin(\mu h)+\frac{1-v}{1+v} cos(\mu h)]=0$

$2 \mu h + sin(2 \mu h)=0$

$A = cos^2(\mu_{n} h) - \frac{2}{1+v}$

$C = \mu_{n}$

In the text, the author finds the eigenvalues first, and then plugs into the original equations to find the last two.

Comment: you are going to need to type it in. I clicked on your link and it sent me to some weird location, which also had some lines of mathematics..

Comment: Does this url work? https://m.imgur.com/gallery/VDDQ1R5

Comment: no, it really doesn't. I'm not going to look at any others. Here is one item on Meta that seems to give beginner lessons in typesetting with MathJax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: OK, they should be added now.

Comment: Hi, did you, by chance, have any advice for solving the problem?